# Как оптимизировать код с кучей картинок?

Tags: android, оптимизация

```
int imageId[]={R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,R.drawable.image9,R.drawable.image10,R.drawable.image11,
        R.drawable.image12,R.drawable.image13,R.drawable.image14,R.drawable.image15,R.drawable.image16,
        R.drawable.image17,R.drawable.image18};
```

Как можно это все вставить в String.xml? int.xml нету.

```
    <string-array name="imageName">
    <item>Мацарелло</item>
    <item>Кранрелло</item>
    <item>Фишняк</item>
    <item>Крутяк</item>
    <item>Маловатов</item>
    <item>Многовато</item>
    <item>Татомато</item>
    <item>Малотомата</item>
    <item>Роллы</item>
    <item>Серенадо</item>
    <item>Нкоа</item>
    <item>нуказакусика</item>
    <item>фишнитяс</item>
    <item>мантинас</item>
    <item>ананас</item>
    <item>масав</item>
    <item>сывввы</item>
    <item>Оллов</item>
</string-array>
```

Вот по такой же аналогии надо вставить их сюда. Только не в виде Stringa, а типа INT.

Просто жалко, что в Android разработке нет ничего такого наподобие Атласа, чтобы хранить, допустим, 100 картинок в одном упакованном файле и после можно было просто обращаться к нему по индексу.

Comment: Как-то много букв. А что Вам мешает сделать свой xml и распарсить его так, как надо?

Comment: Маленький пример можно в студию, хоть глянуть, как это.
_____
Просто если я так буду в коде писать, то это будет как-то некрасиво смотреться.

int imageId[]={R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,R.drawable.image9,R.drawable.image10,R.drawable.image11,R.drawable.image12,R.drawable.image13,R.drawable.image14,R.drawable.image15,R.drawable.image16,R.drawable.image17,R.drawable.image18};

Comment: <image-pack>
  <image name="MyName" resourceName="@resourseName"/>
...
</image-pack>

И написать класс который будет этот xml парсить и выдавать всё что надо методами, например getImageByIndex(int index) который будет возвращать нужные данные.

Comment: @Чад, integer_array в String.xml тоже не работает, он ругается на R.drawable.img1, тоесть туда можно только целое значеие вписывать.

Comment: Попробуйте просто array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаем string-array с **именами картинок**:

```
<string-array name="images">
    <item>image1</item>
    <item>image2</item>
    <item>image3</item>
    <item>image4</item>
    <item>image5</item>
    <item>image6</item>
    <item>image7</item>
</string-array>
```

Достаем ресурсы по имени:

```
String[] images = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.images);
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier(images[i], "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

И теперь с этими drawable делаем, что хотим.

Возможно, потребуется добавить в string-array также и расширение файла, не могу вспомнить точно...

Comment: @metalurgus, еще вопрос: а как в папке drawable создать 5 папок и чтоб в каждой папке были картинки. У меня их 300 штук. И если я создам папку, то после уже не получиться достучаться до ресурса, находящегося в папке, который находится в drawable, то есть /drawable/imageDoom/тут картинки. R.drawable. Тут папка imageDoom не отображается.

Comment: @xTIGRx так, как вы хотите - нельзя сделать.

Comment: @Andreich, А как тогда поступить? просто не понятно будет выглядеть если так сделать в папке drawable закинуть 300 картинок, и назвать их image1...image300, как нибудь сгрупировать их можно хотя бы? по папкам закинуть

Comment: А зачем Вам это? Не забывайте что элементы drawable масштабируются под разные экраны. хотите сгруппировать - называйте group1.image1...